# como puedo resolver el problema de java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, jsf

tengo una clase para un login y cuando hago el login me sale esto:

> com.logic.Docente no se puede convertir en com.logic.Docente

He tratado de asignar una variable a la sesión más sin embargo me sale este error, siempre me toca que reiniciar el servidor ya llevo más de 3 semanas en esto y es algo incomodo ya.

Éstos son mis métodos.

```
/**
 * *
 * Metodo para login de docente
 *
 * @return la pagina redireccionando al docente al index
 */
public String loginUser() {
    try {
        TypedQuery<Docente> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Docente.Login", Docente.class);
        query.setParameter("user", user);
        query.setParameter("password", password);
        if (query.getResultList().size() > 0) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userTeacherSesion", query.getResultList().get(0));
            return "Views/IndexTeacher";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    message = "usuario o password incorrecta";
    return "";
}


/**
 * *
 * metodo para obtener el id del docente
 *
 * @return El objeto con la sesion
 */
public Docente getDocenteSesion() {
    return (Docente) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userTeacherSesion");
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.logic.Docente cannot be
>   cast to com.logic.Docente     at
>   com.controller.LoginController.getDocenteSesion(LoginController.java:120)

Comment: yo probaría para ver que es lo que me está retornando este método: Object objeto = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userTeacherSesion");  Y luego vería que clase me está generando ese get y si es o no nulo. O sea System.out.println ("clase = "+o.getClass(); Para ver que clase está retornando. Ya lo hiciste?

Comment: @AlbertoLopez si amigo siempre toca que estar reiniciando el servidor de glassfish la verdad no se por que me sale esto, incluso hay ocaciones que corre normal el programa.